# Getting data from dataset

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I have got a problem, I have got a filled dataset, but now i need to get a Column value from it and store it into a variable. On Button 2 click i fill it with this:

> tbaGridview.Fill(BlGridview1.vwBLcontainerCargo, Bookingnumber)

Now i want to get the data from it that is inside. I have got a for loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.DataRowCount - 1
    Dim OriginSealNumber As String = BlGridview1.vwBLcontainerCargo.Tables("SEALNUMBER").Rows(i).Item(0)


    Next i
```

But it says Tables is not a member of windowsapplication1.blgridView.vwBLContainerCargoDataTable. How do i get the data for each column??

Comment: which DataSet or DataTable are you using to fill the DataGrid?

Comment: blGridView.xsd is my dataset, my bindingsource is BlGridView1.vwBLcontainerCarg and my tableadapter is tbaGridView

Comment: then iterate through the DataSet.Tables("") or DataGridView.Rows  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-8

Comment: I've got this: Dim OriginSealNumber As String = BlGridview1.Tables("SEALNUMBER").Rows(i).Item(0) But this doesnt get the data instead it gets me a nullpointer exception :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by using this:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.DataRowCount - 1

        Dim OriginSealNumber As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("SEALNUMBER").ToString()
        Dim OriginContainerNumber As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CONTAINERNUMBER").ToString()
        Dim OriginContainerType As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CONTAINERTYPE").ToString()
        Dim OriginQuantity As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("QUANTITY").ToString()
        Dim OriginPackageType As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("PACKAGETYPE").ToString()
        Dim OriginDescription As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("DESCRIPTION").ToString()
        Dim OriginWeight As String = BlGridview1.Tables(0).Rows(i)("WEIGHT").ToString()
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the GridView's table use this sintax:

```
 ((DataRowView)GridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).DataView.Table
```

But I recommend that you use a `BindingSource` object and iterate through it.

Comment: I am new to all this, how to iterate through the bindingsource bsGridView

Comment: This is c# not vb .net what the OP need

Comment: A BindingSource links your database with the controls in your forms, for example a DataGrid, a TextBox, aLabel, etc, when you modify some value in one TextBox the database reflects this changes automatically.